# Auto-Load Vote Counts

Tags: script, voting

## About

This script automatically loads [vote counts](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/established-user) on sites where you have that privilege:

[image: View vote counts]

Currently, you have to click on a vote *score* to see individual up/down counts, but this script loads them automatically when the page loads (if you have the privilege on that site).

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/7899-auto-load-vote-counts) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/7899-auto-load-vote-counts/code/Auto-Load%20Vote%20Counts.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/7899-auto-load-vote-counts/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/7899-auto-load-vote-counts).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.

Comment: The userscript should be changed a bit for it to work still: it needs https instead of http, and the class name has to be changed from `"vote-count-post"` to `"js-vote-count"` on lines 41-43.