# View vote counts without 1k rep automatically

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

### About

Have you ever wished someone combined ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/79306) and [Auto-Load Vote Counts](https://stackapps.com/q/6153/79306)?  Well, now they've been combined!  Vote counts can now auto-load without 1k rep using this script.

#### License

This script is released with the [GNU General Public License v3.0](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later).

#### Download

The script can be downloaded from its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Anonymous941/AutoLoadVoteCountsWithout1kRep).

#### Platform

This script runs on all browsers that support [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) or [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

### Contact

If you found a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), have a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), have [feedback](/questions/tagged/feedback) (shoot, not an actual tag) or for any other reason, post an answer to this question.  If you don't want to post it as an answer for some reason, find me in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The installation procedure is a little tedious:  you must copy the script's text and paste it into a user script manager.

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/Anonymous941/AutoLoadVoteCountsWithout1kRep/pull/1) to change the suffix to`.user.js` so that the user script manager can detect the script automatically

Comment: I've merged the PR, thanks for pointing this out.  Funny, I made [the exact same PR](https://stackapps.com/a/8992/79306) to Spectric's repo yesterday.